# Setting up Azure Federation

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2016, azure-activedirectory

So we use Azure AD and we also have a domain. So we want to connect the Azure AD and the AD from our windows server - but the domain names are different.

The Azure AD is `x.co.uk` and the windows AD is `localdom.x.co.uk`

We don't know how to go about setting it up.

Each Azure AD user has another user on the windows AD - is it possible to link the accounts somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created an alias for the azure domain.

Answer (score 1):

With your want, you could use Azure AD Connect to sync your local to Azure AD. By Synchronizing users’ identities between local and Azure AD, this could let users access different resources in both local and cloud environments. For the details process, you could refer to [here](https://www.codetwo.com/admins-blog/how-to-sync-on-premises-active-directory-to-azure-active-directory-with-azure-ad-connect/).

Comment: Thanks for the response, I ended up creating an alias for the AD